# Move plugin pages from dashboard to front-end

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization

Some time ago I purchased a plugin called school management, I've decided to ask the wonderful WPSE community for some advice.

The plugin is for managing multiple schools. however, I see all the management features are in the back-end. There are two folders that I can see where the content is coming from, namely admin and public in the plugin folder.

I would like to move some of the features in the backend to the frontend. After all, in order to access these pages, you would have to be logged in.

Here is one file with code that displays content in the admin dash.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die();

global $wpdb;

$school_id  = $current_school['id'];
$session_id = $current_session['ID'];

$schools_page_url  = WLSM_M_School::get_page_url();
$students_page_url = WLSM_M_Staff_General::get_students_page_url();
$invoices_page_url = WLSM_M_Staff_Accountant::get_invoices_page_url();

$session_start_date = new DateTime( $current_session['start_date'] );
$session_end_date   = new DateTime( $current_session['end_date'] );
$session_start_date = $session_start_date->format('Y-m-d');
$session_end_date   = $session_end_date->format('Y-m-d');

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_classes' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Classes.
    $total_classes_count  = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::fetch_classes_query_count( $school_id ) );

    // Total Sections.
    $total_sections_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT se.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id JOIN ' . WLSM_SCHOOLS . ' as s ON s.ID = cs.school_id WHERE cs.school_id = %d', $school_id ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_students' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Students.
    $total_students_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sr.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE ss.ID = %d AND cs.school_id = %d', $session_id, $school_id )
    );

    // Students Active.
    $active_students_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sr.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE ss.ID = %d AND cs.school_id = %d AND sr.is_active = 1', $session_id, $school_id )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admins' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Admins.
    $total_admins_count  = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_General::fetch_staff_query_count( $school_id, WLSM_M_Role::get_admin_key() ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_roles' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Roles.
    $total_roles_count = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_General::fetch_role_query_count( $school_id ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_employees' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Staff.
    $total_staff_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_ADMINS . ' as a 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STAFF . ' as sf ON sf.ID = a.staff_id 
            WHERE sf.role = "%s" AND sf.school_id = %d', WLSM_M_Role::get_employee_key(), $school_id )
    );

    // Staff Active.
    $active_staff_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_ADMINS . ' as a 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STAFF . ' as sf ON sf.ID = a.staff_id 
            WHERE sf.role = "%s" AND sf.school_id = %d AND a.is_active = 1', WLSM_M_Role::get_employee_key(), $school_id )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admissions' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Last 15 Admissions
    $admissions = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT sr.ID, sr.name as student_name, sr.enrollment_number, sr.admission_number, sr.admission_date, c.label as class_label, se.label as section_label FROM ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr 
        JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
        JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
        JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
        JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASSES . ' as c ON c.ID = cs.class_id 
        WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d GROUP BY sr.ID ORDER BY sr.admission_date DESC LIMIT 15', $school_id, $session_id )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_invoices' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Invoices.
    $total_invoices_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INVOICES . ' as i 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = i.student_record_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d', $school_id, $session_id )
    );

    // Paid Invoices.
    $invoices_paid_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INVOICES . ' as i 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = i.student_record_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d AND i.status = "%s"', $school_id, $session_id, WLSM_M_Invoice::get_paid_key() )
    );

    // Unpaid Invoices.
    $invoices_unpaid_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INVOICES . ' as i 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = i.student_record_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d AND i.status = "%s"', $school_id, $session_id, WLSM_M_Invoice::get_unpaid_key() )
    );

    // Invoices Partially Paid.
    $invoices_partially_paid_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INVOICES . ' as i 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = i.student_record_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d AND i.status = "%s"', $school_id, $session_id, WLSM_M_Invoice::get_partially_paid_key() )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'stats_payments' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Payments.
    $total_payments_count = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Accountant::fetch_payments_query_count( $school_id, $session_id ) );

    // Total Payment Received.
    $total_payment_received = WLSM_M_Staff_Accountant::get_total_payments_received( $school_id, $session_id );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'stats_amount_fees_structure' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Fees Structure Amount.
    $total_fees_structure_amount = WLSM_M_Staff_Accountant::get_total_fees_structure_amount( $school_id, $session_id );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'stats_expense' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Expenses - Sum.
    $total_expenses_sum = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ep.amount), 0) as sum FROM ' . WLSM_EXPENSES . ' as ep WHERE ep.school_id = %d AND ep.expense_date BETWEEN %s AND %s', $school_id, $session_start_date, $session_end_date ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'stats_income' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Income - Sum.
    $total_income_sum = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COALESCE(SUM(im.amount), 0) as sum FROM ' . WLSM_INCOME . ' as im WHERE im.school_id = %d AND im.income_date BETWEEN %s AND %s', $school_id, $session_start_date, $session_end_date ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_exams' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Exams with Published Timetables.
    $total_exams_with_published_timetables = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(ex.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_EXAMS . ' as ex WHERE ex.school_id = %d AND ex.time_table_published = 1', $school_id ) );

    // Total Exams with Published Admit Cards.
    $total_exams_with_published_admit_cards = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(ex.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_EXAMS . ' as ex WHERE ex.school_id = %d AND ex.admit_cards_published = 1', $school_id ) );

    // Total Exams with Published Results.
    $total_exams_with_published_results = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(ex.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_EXAMS . ' as ex WHERE ex.school_id = %d AND ex.results_published = 1', $school_id ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_library' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Books.
    $total_books = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Library::fetch_book_query_count( $school_id ) );

    // Total Library Cards.
    $total_library_cards = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Library::fetch_library_card_query_count( $school_id, $session_id ) );

    // Total Books Issued.
    $total_books_issued = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Library::fetch_book_issued_query_count( $school_id, $session_id ) );

    // Total Books Return Pending.
    $total_books_return_pending = $wpdb->get_var( WLSM_M_Staff_Library::fetch_book_issued_query_count( $school_id, $session_id, true ) );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_inquiries' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Total Inquiries.
    $total_inquiries_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(iq.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INQUIRIES . ' as iq 
        WHERE iq.school_id = %d', $school_id ) );

    // Inquiries Active.
    $active_inquiries_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(iq.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_INQUIRIES . ' as iq 
        WHERE iq.school_id = %d AND iq.is_active = 1', $school_id ) );

    // Last 10 Active Inquiries
    $active_inquiries = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT iq.ID, iq.name, iq.phone, iq.email, iq.message, iq.created_at, iq.next_follow_up, c.label as class_label FROM ' . WLSM_INQUIRIES . ' as iq 
        JOIN ' . WLSM_SCHOOLS . ' as s ON s.ID = iq.school_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = iq.class_school_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASSES . ' as c ON c.ID = cs.class_id 
        WHERE iq.school_id = %d AND iq.is_active = 1 GROUP BY iq.ID ORDER BY iq.created_at DESC LIMIT 10', $school_id )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_transfer_student' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    // Students Transferred to Other School.
    $students_transferred_to_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sr.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_TRANSFERS . ' as tf 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = tf.from_student_record 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d', $school_id, $session_id )
    );

    // Students Transferred to this School.
    $students_transferred_from_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sr.ID) FROM ' . WLSM_TRANSFERS . ' as tf 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_STUDENT_RECORDS . ' as sr ON sr.ID = tf.to_student_record 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SESSIONS . ' as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_SECTIONS . ' as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
            JOIN ' . WLSM_CLASS_SCHOOL . ' as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
            WHERE cs.school_id = %d AND ss.ID = %d', $school_id, $session_id )
    );
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admissions', 'manage_invoices', 'manage_income', 'manage_expense' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
    require_once WLSM_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'admin/inc/school/staff/general/dashboard/charts.php';

    // Chart settings.
    $settings_charts       = WLSM_M_Setting::get_settings_charts( $school_id );
    $settings_chart_types  = $settings_charts['chart_types'];
    $settings_chart_enable = $settings_charts['chart_enable'];
}
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-3 text-center wlsm-section-heading-block">
            <span class="wlsm-section-heading">
                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                <?php esc_html_e( 'School Dashboard', 'school-management' ); ?>
            </span>
            <?php if ( current_user_can( WLSM_ADMIN_CAPABILITY ) ) { ?>
            <span class="float-right">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" href="<?php echo esc_url( $schools_page_url . '&action=classes&id=' . $school_id ); ?>">
                    <i class="fas fa-layer-group"></i>&nbsp;
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Assign Classes', 'school-management' ); ?>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" href="<?php echo esc_url( $schools_page_url . '&action=admins&id=' . $school_id ); ?>">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i>&nbsp;
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Assign Admins', 'school-management' ); ?>
                </a>
            </span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admissions', 'manage_invoices' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) {
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admissions' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) && ( $settings_chart_enable['monthly_admissions'] ) ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php require_once WLSM_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'admin/inc/school/staff/general/dashboard/charts/monthly_admissions.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_invoices' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) && ( $settings_chart_enable['monthly_payments'] ) ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php require_once WLSM_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'admin/inc/school/staff/general/dashboard/charts/monthly_payments.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php require_once WLSM_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'admin/inc/school/staff/general/dashboard/stats.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_income', 'manage_expense' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) && ( $settings_chart_enable['monthly_income_expense'] ) ) {
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php require_once WLSM_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'admin/inc/school/staff/general/dashboard/charts/monthly_income_expense.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}

if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_inquiries' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) { ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wlsm-stats-heading-block">
            <div class="wlsm-stats-heading">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Last 10 Active Inquiries', 'school-management' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table wlsm-stats-table wlsm-stats-active-inquiries-table">
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Class', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Name', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Email', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Message', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th class="text-nowrap"><?php esc_html_e( 'Date', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th class="text-nowrap"><?php esc_html_e( 'Follow Up Date', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $active_inquiries as $row ) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Class::get_label_text( $row->class_label ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_name_text( $row->name ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_phone_text( $row->phone ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_name_text( $row->email ) ); ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                    if ( $row->message ) {
                        echo esc_html( WLSM_Config::limit_string( $row->message, 50 ) );
                        echo '<a class="text-primary wlsm-view-inquiry-message" data-nonce="' . esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'view-inquiry-message-' . $row->ID ) ) . '" data-inquiry="' . esc_attr( $row->ID ) . '" href="#" data-message-title="' . esc_attr__( 'Inquiry Message', 'school-management' ) . '" data-close="' . esc_attr__( 'Close', 'school-management' ) . '"><span class="dashicons dashicons-search"></span></a>';
                    } else {
                        echo '-';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-nowrap"><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_Config::get_date_text( $row->created_at ) ); ?></td>
                    <td class="text-nowrap"><?php echo esc_html( $row->next_follow_up ? WLSM_Config::get_date_text( $row->next_follow_up ) : '-' ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<?php if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_admissions' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) { ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wlsm-stats-heading-block">
            <div class="wlsm-stats-heading">
                <?php
                printf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: session label */
                        __( 'Last 15 Admissions <small class="text-secondary"> - Session: %s</small>', 'school-management' ),
                        array( 'small' => array( 'class' => array() ) )
                    ),
                    esc_html( WLSM_M_Session::get_label_text( $current_session['label'] ) )
                );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table wlsm-stats-table wlsm-stats-admission-table">
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Student Name', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Enrollment Number', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Class', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Section', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Admission Number', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Admission Date', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $admissions as $row ) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $students_page_url . "&action=save&id=" . $row->ID ); ?>" class="wlsm-link"><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_name_text( $row->student_name ) ); ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( $row->enrollment_number ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Class::get_label_text( $row->class_label ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_section_label_text( $row->section_label ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_M_Staff_Class::get_admission_no_text( $row->admission_number ) ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html( WLSM_Config::get_date_text( $row->admission_date ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'manage_invoices' ), $current_school['permissions'] ) ) { ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wlsm-stats-heading-block">
            <div class="wlsm-stats-heading">
                <?php
                printf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: session label */
                        __( 'Last 15 Payments <small class="text-secondary"> - Session: %s</small>', 'school-management' ),
                        array( 'small' => array( 'class' => array() ) )
                    ),
                    esc_html( WLSM_M_Session::get_label_text( $current_session['label'] ) )
                );

                $can_delete_payments = WLSM_M_Role::check_permission( array( 'delete_payments' ), $current_school['permissions'] );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table wlsm-stats-table wlsm-stats-payment-table">
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Receipt Number', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Amount', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Payment Method', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Transaction ID', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Date', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Invoice', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Student Name', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Admission Number', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Class', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Section', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Phone', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Fahter Name', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Fahter Phone', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <?php if ( $can_delete_payments ) { ?>
                    <th class="text-nowrap"><?php esc_html_e( 'Delete', 'school-management' ); ?></th>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }
```

Comment: If you purchased the plugin you should be eligible for support from the author. They should know better how to adapt their plugin than a general WP community like ours.

Comment: OK, so on this site, nobody has knowledge of how to go about it.. A bit hard to believe.